# Calling a shared library from c++

Tags: c++

i have a shared library with some functions stored inside it. i want to Access those functions by calling that library from another program. I have done this earlier in C.

Now i want to do the same using C++. I am pretty new to C++ and any suggestions are very much required. BTW, the shared library is written in C. Is it still possible for me to call this in a C++ program and use all the functions of it.
Please help me. An example program would be very very helpful.

i am using ubuntu 14.04 and the compiler is the native g++ that comes along with it.

Comment: If you [edit] your question to include some more details such as which dev environment (compiler, linker, etc) and possibly which OS, then it *might* be possible to ask a mod (by pressing the [flag] button) to transfer this question to stack overflow.  As currently written I suspect it would be closed there very quickly due to lack of detail.

Comment: Definitely OS specific.  The way you do this in Windows is completely the way you do it in Linux.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=using+shared+library+linux+C%2B%2B

Comment: @StevenBurnap thanks for the link man. My thought in asking this question is that, someone would have done this many times already and could provide an example.

Comment: [How to call a function from a shared library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538103/how-to-call-a-function-from-a-shared-library)

Answer (score 9):

Load shared libarary using [dlopen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), and load given symbol using [dlsym](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html). Link with `-ldl`.

So given a shared library hello.cpp, compile `g++ -shared -fPIC -o libhello.so hello.cpp`

```
#include <cstdio>

extern "C" void hello( const char* text ) {
  printf("Hello, %s\n", text);
}
```

(shared libraries should be named `lib*.so[.*]`)

Now calling in main.cpp, compile: `g++ -o main main.cpp -ldl`

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C" typedef void (*hello_t)( const char* text );

int main() {
  void* lib = dlopen("./libhello.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  hello_t hello = (hello_t)dlsym( lib, "hello" );

  hello("World!");

  dlclose(lib);
}
```

See [C++ dlopen mini HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/pdf/C++-dlopen.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You said you already did so in C. Actually C++ is based on C, so you still can do it in the same way you did before.

Usually the following steps are required:

- Use some method provided by the library in your c++ code
- Figure out which header provides that method, and include it in your .cpp file
- Compile your C++ code against the headers of the library (compiler flags in the Makefile)
- Link against the library ( Linker Flags in the Makefile )